# Java, Convert multiClient ServertSocket to single

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Long story short, this code is working Perfectly for me. I would like to change the least possible ( While still doing what i want to do ) . This is a multiclient serversocket, that's working great for me. Only thing i want to change is, change it to singleClient.

So that, Client#1 connects, talks to server, Client#2 tries to connect, but can't talk to server since Client#1 is still connected, once Client#1 Disconnects, Client#2 is now able to connect and talk to Server.

Right now my code does exactly that except it allows all the clients to connect and talk to server simultaneously, which is what i don't want.
P.s - The client side is working just fine. Just need help with the Serverside, and one last thing, i'm not JavaSavvy, so spoonfeeding is greatly appreciated :$

```
Socket s=null;
            ServerSocket ss2=null;
            Status = ("Server Listening......");
            try{
                ss2 = new ServerSocket(4445); // can also use static final PORT_NUM , when defined

            }
            catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Server error");

            }


            ServerThread serverThread = null;
            while(true){
                try{
                    s= ss2.accept();
                   Status = ("connection Established");

                   if (serverThread == null || !serverThread.isAlive()) {
                    ServerThread st=new ServerThread(s);    
                    st.start();
                   }
                   else
                       s.close();
                }

            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection Error");

            }
            }

        }




            class ServerThread extends Thread{  


                String str = "Hello";
                String line=null;
                BufferedReader  is = null;
                PrintWriter os=null;
                Socket s=null;

                public ServerThread(Socket s){
                    this.s=s;
                }

                public void run() {
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
                        pw.println("Hi");
                    line=br.readLine();
                    String input = br.readLine().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
                    while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) { //Here is the loop part
                        input = input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
                        if(input.contains("Done")){
                            System.out.println("We closing it");
                            s.close();
                        }
                        else if (input.equals(str)) {
                            System.out.println("We received : " + str);
                            pw.println("Hi");  
                        }
                        if (input.contains(str)){
                                Finite();
                        }
                        if(input.contains("Done")){
                            System.out.println("We closing it");
                            s.close();
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    line=this.getName(); //reused String line for getting thread name
                    System.out.println("IO Error/ Client "+line+" terminated abruptly");
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e){
                    line=this.getName(); //reused String line for getting thread name
                    System.out.println("Client "+line+" Closed");
                }

                finally{    
                try{
                    System.out.println("Connection Closing..");
                    if (is!=null){
                        is.close(); 
                        System.out.println(" Socket Input Stream Closed");
                    }

                    if(os!=null){
                        os.close();
                        System.out.println("Socket Out Closed");
                    }
                    if (s!=null){
                    s.close();
                    System.out.println("Socket Closed");
                    }

                    }
                catch(IOException ie){
                    System.out.println("Socket Close Error");
                }
                }//end finally
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to declare the `ServerThread` instance as a variable, and each time that you accept a new connection, check whether this thread is already connected to a client, and if deny the new connection by closing the socket.

For example:

```
// Keep the server thread as a variable, so we can check if it's already connected.
ServerThread serverThread = null;
while (true) {
    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        Status = ("Connecting accepted");
        if (serverThread == null || !serverThread.isAlive()) {
            // No other client is connected, so start a new thread.
            serverThread = new ServerThread(socket);
            serverThread.start();
            System.out.println("Client connected.")
        } else {
            // A client is already connected, so close the socket.
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Client already connected: connection closed.")
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't solving my proiblem , still let's 2 clients talk to the server, updated the full code after the changes you recommended, no luck yet.

Comment: It's working for me: when the second client connects, the server closes the socket.  What are you seeing?  What do you mean by "talk to the server"?

Comment: Did you check my update after your recommendation?  DId i do it correctly? And what i'm seeing is, the server and all the clients are talking to each other at the same time. ( regarding your last question , as you can tell , this project is basically one server talking to clients by " Hello " and " Hi "

Comment: I've added a couple of `System.out.println()` messages in my solution.  If you run the server, you should see that when the second client connects, the server will print `Client already connected...`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't start the Thread.  You can do this by replacing `s.start()` by `s.run()`.
If you call `s.run()`then the server code will be executed in the main thread.
In your code you can replace:

```
  if (serverThread == null || !serverThread.isAlive()) {
        ServerThread st=new ServerThread(s);    
            st.start();
    }
    else
            s.close();
```

by

```
ServerThread st=new ServerThread(s);   
    st.run();
```

You also don't need the line

```
ServerThread serverThread = null;
```